# I changed the .live methods to .on for loading ajax calls but it's not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I changed everything below from .live to .on and modified the code per many of the discussions I have found, but when I run the code in Visual Studio, I keep getting the below error:

Unhandled exception at line 115, column 5 in http://'server':6665/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js

0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'live'

And the file that Visual Studio is showing as wrong is jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js [dynamic] <-- Where is this file?  It is highlighting the old code with the deprecated .live method before I changed everything below...

I also install the migrate package and that did not work.

```
$(document).on("click", "a[data-ajax=true]", function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    asyncRequest(this, {
        url: this.href,
        type: "GET",
        data: []
    });
});

$(document).on("click", "form[data-ajax=true] input[type=image]", function (evt) {
    var name = evt.target.name,
        $target = $(evt.target),
        form = $target.parents("form")[0],
        offset = $target.offset();

    $(form).data(data_click, [
        { name: name + ".x", value: Math.round(evt.pageX - offset.left) },
        { name: name + ".y", value: Math.round(evt.pageY - offset.top) }
    ]);

    setTimeout(function () {
        $(form).removeData(data_click);
    }, 0);
});

$(document).on("click", "form[data-ajax=true] :submit", function (evt) {
    var name = evt.target.name,
        form = $(evt.target).parents("form")[0];

    $(form).data(data_click, name ? [{ name: name, value: evt.target.value }] : []);

    setTimeout(function () {
        $(form).removeData(data_click);
    }, 0);
});

$(document).on("submit", "form[data-ajax=true]", function (evt) {
    var clickInfo = $(this).data(data_click) || [];
    evt.preventDefault();
    if (!validate(this)) {
        return;
    }
    asyncRequest(this, {
        url: this.action,
        type: this.method || "GET",
        data: clickInfo.concat($(this).serializeArray())
    });
});
```

Thanks! 
Tony

Comment: what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: I upgraded from 1.83, I think to 1.91.

Answer (score 1):

I added jquery migrate plugin and included that in bundles.config file

```
PM> Install-Package jQuery.Migrate
```

and then in bundlesConfig.cs

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                   "~/Scripts/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

Answer (score 0):

.Live was removed from jquery 1.9+
http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/

You should upgrade `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` as it is dependent on an older jquery version.

Comment: I did the jquery update through nugget, is that file not included?  I made the changes per the code above in the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js and the min file...  Sorry I'm a little new to all this jquery stuff...

Comment: I actually just found a fix and got it working via the migrate package (I forgot to add it to the bundle), but that still doesn't explain why this isn't working with the manual changes I made to the code above.  From what I read, that's all that should be required...

Comment: Did you make the changes to both the minified and unmagnified versions?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to make some modifications to a C# project that experienced errors with $("foo").live(). The change to $("foo").on() also presented an error for me due to the dynamic script.

You are seeing the old code because it is cached. For IE 11 do the following: Internet Options -> General -> Browsing History -> Settings -> Check for newer versions very time I start IE. Or, every time you access a page if you like.